# Meaning of "with a guilty air"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Next morning I woke at my usual hour, feeling like a bottle of champagne. I put out my feet and invented a long conversation in which Mrs. Right talked of the trouble she had with her own father till she put him in the Home. I didn’t quite know what the Home was but it sounded the right place for Father. Then I got my chair and stuck my head out of the attic window. Dawn was just breaking, **with a guilty air** that made me feel I had caught it in the act. My head bursting with stories and schemes, I stumbled in next door, and in the half-darkness scrambled into the big bed. There was no room at Mother’s side so I had to get between her and Father. For the time being I had forgotten about him, and for several minutes I sat bolt upright, racking my brains to know what I could do with him. He was taking up more than his fair share of the bed, and I couldn’t get comfortable, so I gave him several kicks that made him grunt and stretch. He made room all right, though. Mother waked and felt for me. I settled back comfortably in the warmth of the bed with my thumb in my mouth. "Mummy!" I hummed, loudly and contentedly. 
>   "Sssh! dear," she whispered. "Don’t wake Daddy!"

Dose it refer to the Sun and means:The sun comes up so slowly as if it has done something wrong? Or does it a metaphor and the boy see the Sun as himself?

This context is from a short story named:"My Oedipus Complex" by Frank O'Connor

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the sun, and says that the sun rose as if it had done something wrong. But I can't tell if the sun seemed slow to the narrator, or what about the sun made the narrator think it seemed guilty. Obviously this is a personification.

In general "... with an {X-adjective} air" means in an manner as if X. or a manner suggesting X. Whether the narrator is identifying himself with the sun is not clear. It is possible, but nothing really sugests it.