# What does someone's "travelled air" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The full paragraph is from James Joyce, so it's about 100 years old, here it is:

> Eight years before he had seen his friend off at the North Wall and wished him godspeed. Gallaher had got on. You could tell that at once by his **travelled air**, his well-cut tweed suit, and fearless accent. Few fellows had talents like his and fewer still could remain unspoiled by such success. Gallaher's heart was in the right place and he had deserved to win. It was something to have a friend like that.

https://esl-bits.net/ESL.English.Listening.Short.Stories/A.Little.Cloud/index.html

Comment: If you google **air**, you will find one of the definitions as follows:                                      an impression of a quality or manner given by someone or something.
"she answered with a faint air of boredom"
Similar words: expression, appearance, look, impression, aspect, manner,                                                 So he looked like someone who was an experienced traveller.

Comment: @Ronald, that should be an answer.

Comment: @randomhead I have taken your hint

Comment: ["with a guilty air"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210299/meaning-of-with-a-guilty-air)  This question was recently active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you google air, you will find one of the definitions as follows:

**an impression of a quality or manner given by someone or something.**

"She answered with a faint air of boredom"

Similar words: expression, appearance, look, impression, aspect, manner,

So he gave the impression of being an experienced traveller. –